# Ember filtered model entries count

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to get the number of results of the Ember Data Store filter. E.g

```
var users = this.store.filter('relevantUser', function(user)
{
    return user.get('screenName') == screenName;
});

return user.get('length');
```

But this always seems to return 0. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be `users.get('length');`.
Things to make sure when using filter method of the store.

- First argument is the model type. Assuming you have a model named App.RelevantUser then your query is fine, else if the model is App.User then you should be using 'user'.
- The `var users` is actually a DS.PromiseArray instance and not an array actually. Try doing  this 
  `this.store.filter('relevantUser',function(user){return      user.get('screenName')==screenName}).then(function(relevantUsers){console.log(relevantUsers.get('length'))})`

As store.filter queries the server too we need to wait for the promise to resolve before accessing the results. Otherwise they would be always 0. 
Incase you are using Chrome. Open up Network Tab in Dev Tools and check the network request going to the server when you run the filter query.